# How can i update Account Linking with gactions?

Tags: actions-on-google, account-linking

I want to update account linking information of action on google with gactions or https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/.

When i execute gactions this only update the action information but manifest and account linking are not update.

This is the action.json:

```
{
  "manifest": {
    "displayName": "The MSH",
    "invocationName": "The MSH",
    "shortDescription": "Hub domotico per la gestione della casa",
    "longDescription": "Hub domotico per la gestione della casa e di tutti i dispotivi Wi-Fi",
    "companyName": "MSH",
    "contactEmail": "dsfsd.sdfsf.93@gmail.com",
    "sampleInvocation": [
      "Fammi parlare con the MSH",
      "Voglio parlare con the MSH"
    ],
    "introduction": "Puoi usare questo agent per comunicare con tutti i dispositivi collegati",
    "voiceName": "female_1"
  },
  "accountLinking": {
    "clientId": "sdfsf",
    "clientSecret": "retdrtfer",
    "grantType": "AUTH_CODE",
    "authenticationUrl": "https://sdfs.ngrok.io/oauth",
    "accessTokenUrl": "https://sdfs.ngrok.io/token",
    "assertionTypes": [
      "UNKNOWN_ASSERTION_TYPE"
    ]
  },
  "actions": [{
    "name": "actions.devices",
    "deviceControl": {
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "conversationName": "automation"
    }
  }],
  "conversations": {
    "automation" :
    {
      "name": "automation",
      "url": "https://asdada.ngrok.io/api/home"
    }
  },
  "locale": "it"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF.! Could you please update, what was the research you had done to resolve the issue.

Comment: I ran into the same problem; everything updates correctly but not the `authenticationUrl` and  `accessTokenUrl`. Did you find a solution to the problem?